# How to nest Android APKs so that they can be opened one with the another?

Tags: android, nested, apk

Is there any way to nest APKs so that you can open one with another?

I am looking to wrap a bunch of APKs with some control options that can fire an APK when selected. Even if I can start with one opening one other it would be a start...

I have thus far tried the dex loader to no avail. I am getting a load error in the log dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. An APK is like a Java JAR file which holds metadata and class files. Android doesn't have an equivalent to a Java WAR file. Individual Android apps will have to be installed separately.

Comment: Hmmm that is kind of what I was thinking but what function does the DexFile class provide? From my understanding it allows you to invoke methods of another APK. If this is possible then would it not be possible to invoke it's start method?

Comment: What start method? Android apps are supposed to run in their own vm sandbox. The metadata (AndroidManifest.xml, etc.) inform the system what intents to register, resources available, etc. Found this blog post which may help out a bit: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/controlling-application-separation.html

Comment: By "start method" I am referring to the onCreate method in the Activity defined in the Manifest xml as the main Activity i.e. the method that begins the building of the applications initial visible page. Thanks for the link but what I am hoping to avoid exposing the apks on the phone. I am effectively hoping to make a wrapper that can control the execution of other apks, however to the general punter rummaging around the phone I only want them to see the one APK of the wrapper and not the APKs of the other apps the wrapper controls... Is it possible to do this?

Comment: No. An app exists as a single apk (not counting invoking other apps - apks via intents) and will be visible in the Applications Manager. Its the user's phone and any app that wasn't baked in should be discoverable and uninstallable. Otherwise just bundle all of the functionality in one apk.